# Bind search input to ng-repeat in different controller

Tags: angularjs

I am building a web application using Angular. We have a Twitter-like navigation bar up top with a search box in it. Then we have a bunch of entries below, using the `ng-repeat` directive. I want to be able to bind the search box with the entries below. The challenge is due to the fact that our header and our entries are in two different controllers. If they were in the same controller, then we could do this:

```
<input type="search" ng-model="search">

<div ng-repeat="entry in entries | filter:search">
  {{ entry.text }}
</div>
```

But since in my application the search box is in a different controller, `search` isn't in scope so it's not working.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you put the search string inside a service you can share the data between both controllers.

Here is an example.

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.js"></script>
    <script>
    angular.module('app', []);

    angular.module('app')
    .controller('Ctrl1', function($scope, ShareData) {
        $scope.myData1 = ShareData;
    });

    angular.module('app')
    .controller('Ctrl2', function($scope, ShareData) {
        $scope.myData2 = ShareData;
        $scope.entries = [
            '1',
            '2',
            '3',
            '11'
        ]
    });

    angular.module('app')
    .service('ShareData', function(){
        return {
            search: "1"
        }
    })

</script>
</head>
<body >
<div ng-controller="Ctrl1">
    <h2>Inside Ctrl 1</h2>
    <input type="text" ng-model="myData1.search">    
</div>
<hr>
<div ng-controller="Ctrl2">
    <h2>Inside Ctrl 2</h2>
    <div ng-repeat="entry in entries | filter:myData2.search">
      {{entry}}
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I went this route and it's working for me perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

You can do one thing use $emit on rootscope and capture it in another controller:-

For example:-

```
<input type="search" ng-model="search">

Controller one:-

$scope.$watch('search',function(new){
$rootScope.$emit('update',new);
});

Controller Second:-

$rootScope.$on('update', function (event, data) {
        $scope.search=data;
      });
```

Secondly you can also share data from controller's via service (this one is effective)

```
myApp.factory('Data', function () {

    var data = {
        search: ''
    };

    return {
        getSearch: function () {
            return data.search;
        },
        setSearch: function (search) {
            data.search= firstName;
        }
    };
});
 myApp.controller('FirstCtrl', function ($scope, Data) {

    $scope.firstName = '';

    $scope.$watch('search', function (newValue) {
        if (newValue) Data.setSearch(newValue);
    });
});

myApp.controller('SecondCtrl', function ($scope, Data) {

    $scope.$watch(function () { return Data.getSearch(); }, function (newValue) {
        if (newValue) $scope.search = newValue;
    });
});
```